# Rename Multiple file - Ubuntu Regex

Tags: ubuntu, rename

I got multiple files on my ubuntu server.

```
blue-A00001-001.png
green-A00001-002.png
red-A00001-003.png
white-A00001-004.png
```

etc

I need to rename these files, so it looks like this

```
A00001-001_blue.png
A00001-002_green.png
A00001-003_red.png
A00001-004_white.png
```

Can anyone help please?

Thankyou

Comment: positional, yes? and if not in this form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with [rename](/questions/tagged/rename):

```
rename -n 's/^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^\.]+)/${2}-${3}_${1}/' *.png
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

this is general regex `^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\.(\w+)$`
compatible with all engines

replace `$2-$3_$1.$4`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hcqby1/1)

Comment: No, `\w` is not compatible with all engines. ERE and BRE will not work

Comment: pleas give links to the 2020 version source code of  ERE and BRE engines so i may see they do not support a word class also herd JS supports `\w+` in lookbehinds maybe

Comment: `ERE`  seems working now, but not `BRE`: can test with grep/sed: `sed 's/\w+//g' <<< 'ok123%---'`

Comment: On latest FreeBSD, even with ERE, `\w` doesn't work.

Comment: what is FreeBSD is that the Free Berkley Software Development that implemented Unix 7 around 1983 ? whats thier latest regex update ?